# ImageField Overwrite with different file name in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

HI i  am making a project in django where upload image and render  is there but i want to make the project like it replace the previous image which can be in different name Like if i upload a image first like san.png and second time if i upload sanju.png the previous one should delete automatically and in folder there should be only one image..... How can i **make the logic**??

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models



class Image(models.Model):
        image = models.FileField(upload_to='images', max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it before updating your object:

```
import os 

# obj is an `Image` instance
os.remove(obj.image.path)

# rest of your logic ...
```